# How to add Tiny MICE Editor to drupal form text area

Tags: html, drupal, tinymce, wysiwyg

i have creadted in admin side one form along with text area.I need to apply Tiny MICE  Editor to my form text area. I have alreday Tiny MICE in my drupal application.Please any body suggest to me,how to apply TinyMICE to text area

Answer (score 1):

go to http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg

install it and there are further instructions for the Tiny MICE

at http://drupal.org/node/371459

Cheers,
Vishal

Answer (score 1):

First off you need to download and install the WYSIWYG module

http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg

Then download TinyMCE and install it to sites/all/libraries/tinymce/

Once you've done this go into your config page and click on WYSIWYG profiles. Select TinyMCE for the input format you want to use it with and save.

Then you can click edit to configure TinyMCE to work how and where you want.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're building a module in Drupal 6 using Form API, you should set the textarea format to Full HTML in yourmodule_admin function:

```
$form['group']['textarea_input']['textarea_input_content'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Textarea Title'),
    '#default_value' => t('My default value'),
    '#description' => t('My description for the textarea'),
    '#required' => false,
);

$form['group']['textarea_input']['format'] = filter_form(2);
```